# Change the content of button in custom editor from Visual Studio Tool Window

Tags: c#, properties, editor, vs-extensibility

I am creating a custom editor using the example from git https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/WPFDesigner_XML. Now I have created a Properties Tool Window in that and programmatically opening it on button click of the editor file using the below logic:
    ShowToolWindow(typeof(VariablesToolWindow).GUID)

```
public void ShowToolWindow(Guid guid)  {
    IVsUIShell vsUIShell = (IVsUIShell)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsUIShell));
    IVsWindowFrame frame;
    vsUIShell.FindToolWindow((uint)__VSFINDTOOLWIN.FTW_fForceCreate, ref guid, out frame);
    frame.SetProperty((int)__VSFPROPID.VSFPROPID_FrameMode, VSFRAMEMODE.VSFM_Dock);
    frame.Show();
}
```

My ToolWindow consists of a button which should update the editor button content.

Below is the code which I am using to update the editor button content:

```
ActivityXMLEditorPanel activityXMLEditorPanel = new ActivityXMLEditorPanel();
activityXMLEditorPanel.btnVariables.Content = "New Content";
```

Note: "ActivityXMLEditorPanel" is my editor file which is WPF form.

Could you please guide me what wrong I am doing in my code as the button content is not getting updated.